# Concatenation inserting additional space character while joining the list in tcl. Is there a way to remove it?

Tags: tcl

I am trying to split a variable and wishes to add a suffix to the first field and then later concatenate it with 2nd one using tcl

like

```
san_jose
```

to

```
san_state_jose
```

I can split the code

```
   set tcl_list [split $var_name "_"]
   set new_name [concat [lindex $tcl_list 0] "_state_" [lindex $tcl_list 1]]
   puts $new_name
```

But concatenation unfornatutly inserts additional space character before combining them as shown below

```
   san _state_ jose
```

Could you please  help me correcting that?

-Regards,
Div

Comment: `new_name` is a *list*. That's now Tcl prints lists, by joining the elements with a space (and enclosing the element in braces if required)

Comment: Actually, that's not strictly true. The `concat` command is documented to "joins each of its arguments together with spaces", so new_name is a string, but the spaces are added by the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [`string cat`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M5):

```
set new_name [string cat [lindex $tcl_list 0] "_state_" [lindex $tcl_list 1]]
```

Or if `new_name` doesn't already exist, [`append`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/append.htm):

```
append new_name [lindex $tcl_list 0] "_state_" [lindex $tcl_list 1]
```

Or just good old interpolation:

```
 set new_name "[lindex $tcl_list 0]_state_[lindex $tcl_list 1]"
```

Or maybe `linsert` and `join`:

```
set new_name [join [linsert $tcl_list 1 state] _]
```

Comment: Tcl is almost as good as perl when it comes to There Is More Than One Way To Do It.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve the problem using regsub but I am interested in learning other ways also.

```
   set new_name [regsub {_} $var_name "_state_"]
   puts $new_name
```

-Regards,
D

Answer (score 0):

```
set tcl_list [split san_jose "_"]
set new_name [concat [lindex $tcl_list 0]_state_[lindex $tcl_list 1]]
puts $new_name
```